# Is it possible to make good subnavigation with Grid csss?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Using CSS grid is it possible make the order be: 
1 6 
2 7
3 8
4 9
5 10

```css
header {
  background: #00333333; 
 width: 700px; 
}

ul {
  width: 100%; 
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px; 
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr)); 
}
```

```html
<header>
    <p>Homepage</p>
      <ul calss="subpoints">
      <li>Homepage1</li>
      <li>Homepage2</li> 
      <li>Homepage3</li>
      <li>Homepage4</li>
      <li>Homepage5</li>
      <li>Homepage6</li>
      <li>Homepage7</li>
      <li>Homepage8</li>
      <li>Homepage9</li>
      <li>Homepage10</li>
      </ul>
</header>
```

I don't use flex items and don't wrap every 5 items in div, because I work with dynamic html data, and it can be 20 li tags or more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to do it with the little help of JS and css variables:

```js
let htmlStyles = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector("html"));
let rowNum = parseInt(htmlStyles.getPropertyValue("--rowNum"));
const listItems = document.querySelectorAll(' li');
let nrRows = Math.floor(listItems.length / 2)
document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--rowNum", nrRows);
```

```css
:root {
  --rowNum: 4;
  --colNum: 2;
  --gridHeight: 20px;
}

header {
  background: #00333333; 
  width: 700px; 
}

ul {
  width: 100%; 
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px; 
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--rowNum), var(--gridHeight));
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--colNum), auto);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <p>Homepage</p>
  <ul class="subpoints">
    <li>Homepage1</li>
    <li>Homepage2</li> 
    <li>Homepage3</li>
    <li>Homepage4</li>
    <li>Homepage5</li>
    <li>Homepage6</li>
    <li>Homepage7</li>
    <li>Homepage8</li>
    <li>Homepage9</li>
    <li>Homepage10</li>
  </ul>
</header>
```